# How to escape special character {{ or skip interpretation of a string in visual studio web test

Tags: c#, visual-studio, automation, web-testing

I am coding some web tests for performance testing with visual studio framework. I need to send some word document content in the request body. The body for example would contain this portion: c÷ß_{{÷ÜÔÁ/èt¥dFX‘\0d®D%ËŒ|_?|¸&6

Visual studio complains that it can't find the Context parameter ÷ÜÔÁ/èt¥dFX‘\0d®D%ËŒ|_...
because the two characters {{ are used by the framework to insert a variable (Context parameter) in the form of {{myVar}}.

I need to find a way to either escape this special char or tell the interpreter to not parse the body at all.

A solution with xml format of the tests or the c# coded version would be fine.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you provide a small example of this? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hi Bernard, what do you need me to put in the example other than request1Body.BodyString = "c÷ß_{{÷ÜÔÁ/èt¥dFX‘\0d®D%ËŒ|}}_?|¸&6";

Comment: @YoucefKelanemer please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to see what is meant by a useful example.

Comment: Thanks to all for the answers. I was hoping for something clean like a CDATA in xml but maybe Visual Studio Framework will implement something like that.